# Simplifying the same function with different parameters

Tags: proof-explanation

This is an extremely basic question but I am curious, can the same function be equivalent when it has different parameters.

For instance if let's say I had an equation p(r) = $ \frac {r}{a} $

I then had an equation

E = $ \frac{\int n(r')r}{n(r)} $

In this instance we assume n(r) is proportional to p(r).

n(r) $ \propto $ p(r)

Does this equation then become

E = $ \frac{\int p(r')r}{p(r)} $

and then the p(r) and p(r') terms cancel out of $ \frac{\int p(r')  r}{p(r)} $

leaving just $ \int r$

If so, what is the proof for this.